# Using TypeDescriptor to load custom attributes in a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, custom-attributes, typedescriptor

I have several classes with the following datacontract definition with a metadata class

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ClassAMetadata))]
public partial class ClassA
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}

public class ClassAMetadata
{
    [CustomAttribute(Title = "PropertyAText")]
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}
```

Then I want to obtain from the current assembly the property Title of my CustomAttribute that is used in all of that assembly types, using the following code:

```
internal static Dictionary<string, string> GetCustomAttributeTitles<T>(this T entity) where T : class
{          
    Dictionary<string, string> result = (from prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(entity.GetType()).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                                            from att in prop.Attributes.OfType<CustomAttribute>()
                                            select new { prop.Name, att.Title }).ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t => t.Title);

    return result;
}
```

Before I call the method GetCustomAttributeTitles, I load the metadata attributes in Type descriptor:

```
    public static void InstallForAssembly(Assembly assembly)
    {
        if (assembly == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("assembly");
        }

        foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            foreach (MetadataTypeAttribute attrib in type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetadataTypeAttribute), true))
            {
                TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(
                      new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(type, attrib.MetadataClassType), type);
            }
        }
    }
```

An example of my program would be:

```
InstallForAssembly(Assembly.LoadFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\DataContract.dll"));
ClassA instanceOfA = new ClassA();
//fill instanceOfA
var dictionary = instanceOfA.GetCustomAttributeTitles();
//do something with dictionary
```

This works well in a console application but doesn't work in a WCF Service method, the dictionary in GetCustomAttributeTitles method is always empty. Why does it happens?

Comment: I can't think of any particular reason this won't work in WCF, except maybe the registration of the type descriptor provider (in console its easy, in WCF, especially if its hosted in IIS, it should be added in ServiceHost, or something similar). Maybe you should post a lightweight reproduction of this issue so we can take a look.